# How can I send data to an anonymous class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I send data back to a view when the view is anonymous (I am writing a library that takes a user from his present view to another, then return the users back to the initial view but also with a payload/data). 
In my code I go back to the anonymous previous view using:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

but how do I send data (string or object) along with it? or does flutter have a message dispatcher that is received by all views who listen for it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Navigator.pop(context, data);
```

The caller needs to listen it using

```
var data = await Navigator.push(...);
```